# Get Django ALLOWED_HOSTS env. variable formated right in settings.py

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I'm facing the following issue. My .env files contains a line like:

```
export SERVERNAMES="localhost domain1 domain2 domain3" <- exactly this kind of format
```

But the variable called `SERVERNAMES` is used multiple times at multiple locations of my deployment so i can't declare this as compatible list of strings that settings.py can use imidiatly. beside I don't like to set multiple variables of .env for basically the same thing. So my question is how can I format my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to be compatible with my settings.py. Something like this does not seem to work it seems:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('SERVERNAMES').split(',')
```

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: Does `.split(' ')` solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, many thx for your hint.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply split your `SERVERNAMES` variable using space as separator instead of comma

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('SERVERNAMES').split(' ')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also make use of the env.list command.

Put int your .env file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=example.com,awesomedomain.com,stagingdomain.com
```

and in python use

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list("ALLOWED_HOSTS")
```

Comment: In this case, you can also define env value as a list too.

Answer (score 4):

The coma is making it a string

```
env = "localhost domain1 domain2 domain3"

envs = envs.split(',')

print(envs)

['localhost domain1 domain2 domain3']
```

Instead just split the string with space and python turns it into a list of strings

```
env = "localhost domain1 domain2 domain3"

envs = env.split() # By default `str.split()` splits upon spaces

print(envs)

['localhost', 'domain1', 'domain2', 'domain3']
```