# Dotenv Doesn't Handle Multiple Hosts in ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django, dotenv

In my production setting.py file I have:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(override=True)

DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG')

#ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_HOSTS")
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'www.example.com']
```

In my .env file in production, I have

```
DEBUG=False
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['www.example.com', 'example.com']
```

If I switch the commented out line in settings, I get an error saying url may not be in the allowed hosts. I have a number of other definitions in the .env file that work fine although I'm not sure about debug. I've tried all sorts of combinations on the ALLOWED_HOSTS and get the same error. In development I have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS='localhost'
```

That setting works fine. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: put * in allowed hosts list like `ALLOWED_HOSTS=[*]`

Comment: That will just open up the site to every URL, which isn't what he is looking to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a portion of answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60410625/get-django-allowed-hosts-env-variable-formated-right-in-settings-py). Then I did that :

```
#setting.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(' ') 

#.env
ALLOWED_HOSTS = domain1 domain2 domain3 domain4
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not loading the .env file properly. Try:

```
project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/my-project-dir')  # adjust as appropriate    
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_HOSTS")
```

Documentation: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/

Comment: if I wasn't loading it properly then wouldn't it be the case that none of the variables would be populated. I have my database id and password and secret key. They all seem to be working. That's not say that I didn't just got lucky on the way I'm loading it.

Comment: Ok, I wasn;t aware you were getting anything from it as you didn;t mention that in your question - you just mentioned the one variable, not others. You should update your question to add that information.

Comment: In the original question: " I have a number of other definitions in the .env file that work fine". I should have been more clear.

Comment: Yes, that would help.